# azure chatbot with webchat conversation logging on none of the above option selection by the user

Tags: javascript, html, azure

i am new to the web chat services, and trying to create a chat bot in pure java script code that can easily embed in any html file,
I've refereed the documentation provided by the Microsoft but still i am really confused i want to log user conversation on analytics when user queries something and chat bot returns options with `none of the above` as last option and user select that `none of the above` option

i want to log that data in following way
`{ userQuery : "query written by user to which chatbot returns` none of the above`" botResponse : "options returned but the chatbot (e.g in my case its 4 with`none of the above      option `as last option )" selectedResponse : "none of the above" // user selected option }`

any help is appreciated
Thank you in advance!

any answer would be helpful..

here is the code i've created but its not working as expected  ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Styled Chatbot</title>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js"
    ></script>
    <!-- Application Insights SDK -->

    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }

      body {
        font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden; /* Prevent scrolling of the entire page when chatbot is open */
      }

      #webchat-container {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 65px;
        right: 20px;
        display: none;
        max-width: 560px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 74dvh;
        /* height: 600px; */
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        background-color: #fff;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .wc-header {
        background-color: #0099cc;
        color: white;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        font-size: 18px;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #webchat-header {
        background-color: #0099cc;
        color: white;
        padding: 11px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        /* position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 96%; */
      }

      #webchat-header .close-button {
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      #webchat-header .close-button:hover {
        background-color: #0077a3;
      }

      #webchat-content {
        overflow-y: auto;
        max-height: calc(100% - 110px);
        padding: 10px;
      }
      .webchat__send-box__main {
        bottom: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 50px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
      }
      .webchat__send-box__main div:first-child {
        display: none;
      }
      .webchat__upload-button svg {
        display: none;
      }
      .webchat__upload-button {
        display: none;
      }

      #lets-connect-button {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        background-color: #0099cc;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        transition: background-color 0.3s;
        z-index: 9999; /* Ensure the button is on top of everything */
      }

      #lets-connect-button:hover {
        background-color: #0077a3;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="lets-connect-button">Let's Connect</div>
    <div id="webchat-container">
      <div id="webchat-header">
        Chat Bot
        <div class="close-button">✖</div>
      </div>
      <div id="webchat-content"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var appInsights = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsights({
        config: { instrumentationKey: "instrumentation-key " },
        enableCorsCorrelation: true,
      });
      appInsights.loadAppInsights(); // Load Application Insights

      // Function to toggle the chatbot container
      function toggleChatbot() {
        const webchatContainer = document.getElementById("webchat-container");
        const letsConnectButton = document.getElementById(
          "lets-connect-button"
        );

        if (webchatContainer.style.display === "block") {
          webchatContainer.style.display = "none";
          letsConnectButton.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          webchatContainer.style.display = "block";
          letsConnectButton.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
      document
        .getElementById("lets-connect-button")
        .addEventListener("click", toggleChatbot);

      document
        .querySelector("#webchat-header .close-button")
        .addEventListener("click", toggleChatbot);

      (async function () {
        // Function to fetch the Cognitive Services Speech Services credentials
        function createFetchSpeechServicesCredentials() {
          let expireAfter = 0;
          let lastPromise;

          return () => {
            const now = Date.now();
            
            if (now > expireAfter) {
              expireAfter = now + 300000;
              lastPromise = fetch(
                "https://westus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken",
                {
                  method: "POST",
                }
              ).then(
                // (res) => res.json(),
                (res) => res.text(),
                (err) => {
                  expireAfter = 0;

                  return Promise.reject(err);
                }
              );
            }

            return lastPromise;
          };
        }

        const fetchSpeechServicesCredentials =
          createFetchSpeechServicesCredentials();

        // Create the ponyfill factory function
        const webSpeechPonyfillFactory =
        await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory(
          {
            credentials: fetchSpeechServicesCredentials,
            textNormalization: "lexical",
          }
        );
        

        let userQueries = [];
        const activityLoggerMiddleware = () => {
          // activity logger middleware but not working 

          return (next) => (action) => {
            if (action.activity && action.activity.type === "message") {
              console.log("action: ", action);
              const isUserActivity =
                action.activity.from.role === "user" &&
                action.activity.channelData.state === "sent";

              if (isUserActivity) {
                console.log("query----------- ");
                if (
                  action.activity.channelData.clientActivityID &&
                  // action.activity.text !== "None of the above." &&
                  action.activity.text !== userQueries[userQueries.length - 1]
                ) {
                  if (
                    action.nextVisibleActivity &&
                    action.nextVisibleActivity.text !== "No answer found"
                  ) {
                    console.log(" action.nextVisibleActivity: =======", action);
                    userQueries.push(action.activity.text);
                    console.log("userQueries: ", userQueries);

                    if (action.activity.text === "None of the above.") {
                      sendTrackEvent(action);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }

            return next(action);
          };
        };

        const activityLoggerMiddleware2 = () => (next) => (context) => {
          if (
            /** user send query and its associated response comes in nextVisibleActivity */
            context.nextVisibleActivity &&
            context.activity.channelData.state === "sent"
          ) {
            console.log("context: ", context);
          }

          return next(context);
        };

        function onNoneOfTheAboveSelectionLogActivity(
          from,
          userQuery,
          selectedOption
        ) {
          appInsights.trackEvent({
            name: "NoneOfTheAboveSelected",
            properties: {
              from: from + "-testing",
              userQuery,
              selectedOption,
            },
          });
        }
        // Pass a Web Speech ponyfill factory to renderWebChat
        window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
          {
            directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
              secret: "directline-secret",
            }),
            activityMiddleware: [activityLoggerMiddleware2],
            webSpeechPonyfillFactory,
          },
          document.getElementById("webchat-content")
        );
      })().catch((err) => console.error(err));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler for incoming user messages and outgoing bot messages.

```js
const userQueries = []; // Store user queries with timestamps or identifiers

const activityLoggerMiddleware = () => {
  return (next) => (action) => {
    if (action.activity && action.activity.type === "message") {
      const isUserActivity =
        action.activity.from.role === "user" &&
        action.activity.channelData.state === "sent";

      if (isUserActivity) {
        // Generate a timestamp or unique identifier for each user query
        const timestamp = new Date().getTime(); // You can customize this as needed
        userQueries.push({ timestamp, query: action.activity.text });
      }
    }

    return next(action);
  };
};

function logUserQuery(userQuery) {
  // Store the user query along with a flag indicating it's NOTA-related
  userQueries.push({ query: userQuery, isNotaRelated: false });
}

function logNoneOfTheAbove(selectedOption) {
  // Find the most recent user query associated with NOTA
  const notaRelatedQuery = userQueries
    .slice()
    .reverse()
    .find((query) => query.isNotaRelated);

  if (notaRelatedQuery) {
    // Log "None of the above" selection with the associated user query
    appInsights.trackEvent({
      name: "NoneOfTheAboveSelected",
      properties: {
        userQuery: notaRelatedQuery.query,
        botResponse: "Your bot response options here", // Replace with actual options
        selectedOption: selectedOption,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

- In the above script you can see the modified **activityLoggerMiddleware** by this we can log both user and bot messages.

I created an azure bot service and implemented a bot service application and from below I taken direct line secret key to access.

[image]

- we can configure Application Insights in the code as shown in below.

```js
var appInsights = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsights({
  config: { instrumentationKey: "your-instrumentation-key" },
  enableCorsCorrelation: true,
});
```

Or directly configure in the bot service only.

[image]

By this when the user selects **None of the above**, it will log the user query, bot response, and the selected response in Application Insights.

Comment: When I select the 'none of the above' option, I believe a new query with that option's name is generated: 

in context to activityLoggerMiddleware, If I choose the option, it will return 'none of the above' as the new user query.

There is one scenario that I believe will not work with that method.
When a user selects NOTA and continues to chat after 2 to 4 discussion exchanges between bot and webchat-user, I believe it will return the most recent user query, however we need to acquire the userquery associated with the NOTA option.

Please provide me with further information about it.

Comment: Hi Shubham kashyap, I just modified the code that when a user selects **None of the above**, that associated user query is stored with the **isNotaRelated** flag set to true and when you need to log the "None of the Above" selection, you can find the most recent user query associated with NOTA and log it accordingly.

Comment: Hello, Suresh Chikkam. Thank you for providing the needed information. There is one scenario that I believe will not work with the provided context. Consider three to four different userQueries that have a NOTA option in the coversation. I believe that the context provided will always give the most recent one. What if the user selects the second or first one NOTA option?  we need to acquire the userquery associated with the selected NOTA option.

Comment: The code which I edited will store and use the specific user query associated with the selected NOTA option, even if there are multiple NOTA options in the conversation. It captures the correct user query by tracking both the user queries and their associated NOTA selections in the notaSelections data structure.